# How to pass c# decimal to sql decimal(4,2)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm creating web page that saves data from a form to a sql table. One of the data points in C# is a decimal. When I try to send the to Sql Server I get this error:

> "Error converting data type numeric to numeric."

I am able to send `SqlDecimal.Null`, and that works. The problem only happens when I have an actual value. I tested when the Sql value is `1.00` which should easily fit in a SQL `decimal(4,2)`.

Here is the code:

```
sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("hoursPerWeek", SqlDbType.Decimal)
{
   SqlValue = hoursPerWeek==null ? SqlDecimal.Null : new sqlDecimal((decimal)hoursPerWeek)
});
```

With this code, if `hoursPerWeek` is `null`, the value is properly saved to the db.
But if the value is `1.00`, I get the error.

Comment: What type is `hoursPerWeek`? `Nullable<decimal>`?

Comment: Yes, hoursPerWeek is Nullable<decimal>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sqlParams` is an `SqlParameterCollection` and `hoursPerWeek` is `Nullable<decimal>`:

```
sqlParams.Add("@hoursPerWeek", SqlDbtype.Decimal, 4, 2).Value = hoursPerWeek  == null ? DBNull.Value : hoursPerWeek.Value;
```

The original code mapped to a `decimal` type on Sql Server (which is a synonym for `numeric`), but did not specify the precision or scale, thus using defaults for precision and scale which were not compatible with `(4,2)`.

Comment: sqlParams is a List<SqlParameter>

That syntax doesn't work, but even converting it to
`sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("hoursPerWeek", SqlDbType.Decimal)
                {
                    Precision = 4,
                    Scale = 2,
                    Value = hoursPerWeek == null ? SqlDecimal.Null : hoursPerWeek.Value
    });`
doesn't work, still getting the same error.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the next level, in the data layer, just before the query is executed, and check the parameter value in the debugger.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I think you are going to get a compile time error like: "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'decimal'".

Comment: .. or could use something like:  Value = hoursPerWeek ?? (object)DBNull.Value;

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it working with this:

```
sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("hoursPerWeek", hoursPerWeek == null ? (decimal?)null : decimal.Round((decimal)hoursPerWeek, 2)));
```